# How to reset value after button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple app in which user provides a number and square is generated with the given number. The problem is that when the user provides the input the first time, it works as intended, but when the user edits the value and clicks the button, the value adds with the existing value and it displays the square of the sums. I want to reset the input after the button click, but haven't got any clue how to do. Any solutions

The html code looks like this

```
<div class="intro">
   <h1>Select no of squares to be made</h1>
   <small>This experience is better with the values between 400 and 600</small>
   <input type="number" id="squaresInput">
   <button class="show">Go</button>
</div>
```

And js file is

```
const userInput = document.getElementById('squaresInput')
const btnInput = document.querySelector('.show')
btnInput.addEventListener('click', () => getUserInput())
let squaresNum

function getUserInput(){
    let squaresNum = userInput.value

    for(let i = 0; i < squaresNum; i++){
        const square = document.createElement('div')
        square.classList.add('square')
    
        square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => setColor(square))
        square.addEventListener('mouseout', () => removeColor(square))
    
        container.appendChild(square)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `userInput.value = "";` at the end of function, which will clear out any existing value in the input.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById('squaresInput')
const btnInput = document.querySelector('.show')
btnInput.addEventListener('click', () => getUserInput())
let squaresNum;

function getUserInput(){
    let squaresNum = userInput.value

    for(let i = 0; i < squaresNum; i++){
        const square = document.createElement('div')
        square.classList.add('square')
    
        square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => setColor(square))
        square.addEventListener('mouseout', () => removeColor(square))
    
        container.appendChild(square)
    }
    
    userInput.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
   <h1>Select no of squares to be made</h1>
   <small>This experience is better with the values between 400 and 600</small>
   <input type="number" id="squaresInput">
   <button class="show">Go</button>
   <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
userInput.value = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start moving
`const userInput = document.getElementById('squaresInput')`
into "getUserInput()" function.
Then removing the "let squaresNum" outside the function, it is useless.

Gianluca

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this before adding more squares.

```
container.innerHTML = ""
```

at the beginning of

```
function getUserInput () {....
```

In this way you will eliminate the squares previously created before creating the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of using `<form>`.

1. Change `<div class='intro'>` to `<form id='intro'>`
2. Whatever `.container` is change it to `<fieldset id='container'>` or `name='container'`. If you don't want the border, in CSS `.container {border:0;}`
3. Now you just register the `'submit'` event to the `<form>`

   1. When any `<button>`, `<input type='submit'>`, or `<button type='submit'>` is clicked or a form control has focus and user keys <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> the `'submit'` event is triggered.
   2. `event.preventDefault()` is to stop the `<form>` from trying to send data to a server.
   3. `this.reset();` will clear the `<input>`
4. Unless `setColor()` and `removeColor()` do more than just change `div.square` color, it's better just to use CSS. `.square {border-color: red; background: red}`
5. Using a `<form>` allows you to use the [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form) and [`HTML Forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form) API. It's terse and specific which allows more control and less coding.

```
// Reference a `<form>`
const f = document.forms['id'] /*OR*/ document.forms.id // name can be used as well

// Reference all form controls within <form>
const io = f.elements;

// Reference a form control within <form>
const btn = io['id'] /*OR*/ io.id // name can be used as well
```

6. Use [`createDocumentFragment();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) because 400 to 600 nodes to render is really too much.
7. Also added a `<button>` to clear out the squares whenever the user wishes to.
8. Added `'mouseover/out'` event handler. It's registered to the parent element only and not to each `.square`. This and the `'submit'` event are possible because of [Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) and how [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) leverages it.
   In the event handler `hoverGrid()` values, expressions, statements, and functions (ex. `addColor()` and `removeColor()`) can be placed within the appropriate `case` of the `switch()`.

```
...
case 'mouseover':
  addColor();
  break;
case 'mouseout':
  removeColor();
  break;
...
```

```js
const I = document.forms.intro;
const io = I.elements;
const clr = io.clr;
const box = io.box;

I.onsubmit = createGrid;

clr.onclick = clearGrid;

box.onmouseover = hoverGrid;
box.onmouseout = hoverGrid;

function createGrid(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let cnt = parseInt(io.qty.value);
  let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    let square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'square';
    square.dataset.index = i + 1;
    frag.appendChild(square);
  }
  box.appendChild(frag);
  this.reset();
  console.clear();
  console.log(box.childElementCount);
};

function clearGrid(event) {
  this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '';
};

function hoverGrid(event) {
  let E = event.type;
  const sqr = event.target;

  if (sqr.matches('.square')) {
    switch (E) {
      case 'mouseover':
        console.log(sqr.dataset.index);
        break;
      case 'mouseout':
        console.clear();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-family: Consolas;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit
}

small {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

button {
  width: 4ch;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 96vw;
  height: max-content;
}

.square {
  width: 1ch;
  height: 1ch;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.square:hover {
  border-color: red;
  background: red;
}

#clr {
  width: 9ch;
  float: right;
}


/* SO Console Display - Rightside Column */

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 20% !important;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="intro">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select no. of squares to be made</legend>
    <small>This experience is better with the values between 400 and 600</small>
    <input type="number" id="qty" min='0' max='1000'>
    <button>GO</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='box'></fieldset>
  <button id='clr' type='button'>CLEAR</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that I couldn't fully clarify the program to you. The program is a hoverboard one, in which you hover around the squares and it will fill with a random one. With your code it would drastically change the objective of the program. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: @throwaway198526 IC, I'll update later that's an easy modification.